# How do I purge the gallery on my Samsung Note 3

Tags: samsung, gallery

All of the pictures I ever took with my old phone were automatically backed up to my google account, thousands of pictures of stupid things, receipts, flight schedules and private pictures.

With my new phone, a Samsung Note 3, all of these images are now in my gallery.
I can find the offending images on picasaweb, no way I could find them on google+

So, what I would like to do, is purge wherever the files from my online pictures are downloaded to, remove the backup pictures from picasaweb and let the phone sync again.

TLDR

Where are the picasaweb/google+ images downloaded to on this phone?

Comment: Have you tried unchecking Google+ Photos and/or Picasa web albums from the sync menu in Settings > Google?

Answer (score 1):

With the Note 3 do the following:

Open 
-settings

-General

-accounts

-Google

uncheck'Sync Picasa Web Albums'

The "gallery" button is found in **General> applications manager**

Select **All**

Scroll down and select Gallery

Tap **Clear Data**